# 401 full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: authentication, get, request

i'm trying to retrieve json data from my local API Server, using get request. I always receive this error. I already visit many sites, but i haven't find solution to this problem. 
Does anybody know why and how to fix it? If it's needed more configuration information, let me know, thanks

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from "angular2/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Headers} from "angular2/http";
import {Jsonp} from "angular2/http";

@Injectable()
export class HTTPTestService{
    constructor(private _http: Http){}

 getCurrentTime(){

        console.log('je suis le test0');
        console.log(this._http.get('http://localhost:9090/webservices/pivot/rest/v1/cube/discovery').map(res  => res.json()));
        console.log('je suis le test10');
  return this._http.get('http://localhost:9090/webservices/pivot/rest/v1/cube/discovery')
            .map(res  => res.json());
    }
 postJSON(){
        var json=JSON.stringify({var1: 'test', var2: 3});
        var params = 'json=' + json;
        var headers = new  Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        return this._http.post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
            params,{
                headers: headers
            })
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, i put an authorization on the headers; and it works fine!
let see the solution here:

```
  getCurrentTime(){
        console.log('je suis le test0');
        var headers = new  Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=');

        return this._http
            .get('http://localhost:9090/webservices/pivot/rest/v1/cube/discovery', {headers: headers})
            .map(res  => res.json().data);
    }
```